# get related products on product category page Magento

Tags: magento, razor

I am working on a magento project, in which I need to show a
related products of a each product on product category page  along
with a main product.

Can you please suggest how can I do this and get related products on list page. I have follow [this link](http://www.magentobooker.com/magento-get-related-products-by-product-id), but cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you will create custom template file & call into list page
like catalog/product/list/related.phtml